# Fitting ionic tabs(Left icon tabs) to the screen

Tags: tabs, ionic-framework

[This is my browser output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkBT2.png)I am making my first ionic app.I want my tab(containing home,favorites and settings button) to be displayed at the bottom of my screen instead of displaying right after the "lets go!" button.Do we have to position it using css or is there any easier way to do it.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive"` in your  directive.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">
</ion-tabs>
```

I have made a small demo for you. Surely it will help you.

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0TLWGW?p=preview)

If you need any additional feature.Please let me know?
Thanks

Comment: Thanq mushin that was very helpful.I want my text and button (written after my header)  to be displayed exactly at the center of my app, i tried some stuff but was not successful. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you draw a picture as per your requirement?

Comment: I have a header and a footer.In between the header and footer i have a paragraph containing two lines followed by a button.I want this paragraph and button to be displayed right at the center of my screen.Sorry i cant draw it here.

Comment: nope are you on facebook?. If yes i could send you the design.

Comment: yeah.My user name is MuhZi Eramam

Comment: please check your facebook account i've sent you  req